# Синхронизация кнопок с календарем Android приложение

Tags: java, android

Есть ли такая возможность и, если есть, то каким образом можно синхронизировать некоторое количество кнопок с календарем на телефоне?

То есть, когда наступает определенный день - кнопка становится активной для срабатывания, до этого времени `button.setEnabled(false);` (недоступна).

Comment: Можете попробовать сделать кнопку невидимой (invisible/gone), а когда наступит определённый день - изменить видимость на visible.